# How to trigger a distant element that associates with the current button?

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseevent, contains

How can I trigger the distant element which associates with the current button?

For instance,

HTML

```
<ul class="menu-1">
    <li><a href="#">button 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">button 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">button 2</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="menu-2">
    <li><a href="#">button 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">button 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">button 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

So when I hover the **button 1** in `menu-1`, the **button 1** in `menu-2` should be hovered too.

And so when I hover the **button 1** in `menu-2`, the **button 1** in `menu-1` should be hovered too.

my working jquery,

```
$(".menu-1 li").hover(function () {

        var text = $(this).text();

        if ($('.menu-2 li a:contains("'+text+'")').length > 0) {
            $('.menu-2 li a:contains("'+text+'")').trigger("mouseenter");
        }
    });
```

jsfiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/JDG7U/

Comment: Is there no way you can use either `id`, `class` or `data-x` attributes to identify the relations between the elements? Matching by text content is rather slow and ugly. Also, what happens if you have `button 1` in menu 1, and `button 11` in menu 2. They would match when using `:contains`

Comment: yes it is not necessary to match by text, any better suggestions/ solutions are welcomed. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach I used is to replace your `:hover` with a `.hover` class and assign the CSS changes to that class. Then I added a `data-` attribute to each `li` and filtered on that. (Using a class caused problems, because I couldn't read an arbitrary class attribute without picking up the `hover` class as well.)

A bit complicated, but it left some pretty short and simple code, and it permits reordering of the elements if you need that.

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu-1">
    <li data-num="1"><a href="#">button 1</a></li>
    <li data-num="2"><a href="#">button 2</a></li>
    <li data-num="3"><a href="#">button 3</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="menu-2">
    <li data-num="2"><a href="#">button 2</a></li>
    <li data-num="3"><a href="#">button 3</a></li>
    <li data-num="1"><a href="#">button 1</a></li>
</ul>​
```

JS:

```
$('ul li').hover(function() {
    var num = $(this).data('num');
    $('li').filter(function() {
        return $(this).data('num') === num;
    }).toggleClass('hover');
});​
```

CSS:

```
ul li.hover a {
    color: green;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/he7Uk/2/

Comment: thanks for the answer, mblase. loved its simplicity! but I wonder whether this is a valid html by adding `data-num="x"` to the li element?

Comment: @lauthiamkok Yes, that's a valid HTML5 attribute, and even HTML4 allows the addition of new attributes to the tag (which will be ignored if they're not recognized). jQuery automatically imports all `data-` attributes for use with the `.data()` method, which makes it a convenient way to store arbitrary data in the DOM elements themselves.

Comment: `that's a valid HTML5 attribute, even HTML4 allows the addition of new attributes to the tag (which will be ignored if they're not recognized)` great to know this! thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know you can't really trigger pseudo classes like :hover in that way, but you could use a class or set the styles in a mouseenter/mouseleave event in JS, or just change the CSS directly, something like:

```
$(".menu-1 li").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
       var index = $(this).index();
       $('.menu-2 li a').eq(index).css('color', 'green');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
       var index = $(this).index();
       $('.menu-2 li a').eq(index).css('color', 'black');
    }
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/JDG7U/3/)

or with classes, working both ways:

```
$(".menu-1 li, .menu-2 li").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        var index = $(this).index(),
            elems = $('.menu-1 li a:eq('+index+'), .menu-2 li a:eq('+index+')');
        $(elems).addClass('hover');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        var index = $(this).index(),
            elems = $('.menu-1 li a:eq('+index+'), .menu-2 li a:eq('+index+')');
        $(elems).removeClass('hover');
    }
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/JDG7U/6/)

Comment: Good answer, but I dislike the assumption that the elements in each list will always be in the same order as each other.

Comment: @mblase75 - Yes, they would have to be in the right order, otherwise some sort of identifier is required, like your data attributes etc. or using the content to identify them. The last not being very efficient still works thou. Only way I could think of without changing the HTML markup and not using the content was using the index instead.

Answer (score 1):

And one more variant using `:nth-child`:

```
$lis = $('.menu li');
$lis.hover(function() {
    var index = $(this).index() + 1;
    $lis.filter(':nth-child(' + index + ')').addClass('hovered');
}, function() {
    $lis.removeClass('hovered');
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JDG7U/5/

Answer (score 0):

Give them both the same `.class`

Comment: Please explain with a concrete code example. I suspect it won't work as easily as you seem to think.